# Serial number of certs in BasicOCSPResponse is not the same with the certificate

Tags: certificate, wireshark, ocsp

I want to know how a browser check the validity of a certificate with [OCSP stapling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling), to make sure the certificate is not expired or revoked.

I used wireshark to capture tls packets with [bing.com](https://bing.com).

Looked into Server hello packet `Server Hello, Certificate, Certificate Status, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done`.[image]

Looked into `certificate status` field, and I can see `OCSP response`, which is what I need.

Went into `BasicOCSPResponse`, its structure ([rfc6960](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6960)) is:

```
   BasicOCSPResponse       ::= SEQUENCE {
      tbsResponseData      ResponseData,
      signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
      signature            BIT STRING,
      certs            [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE OF Certificate OPTIONAL }
```

So I clicked into `certs`, is looks like this:
[image]

I have highlighted `serial number`, which should be the serial number of the bing certificate, but I cannot match it with the certificates I downloaded from bing (see them [here](https://ssltools.digicert.com/checker/views/checkInstallation.jsp?domain=bing.com&port=443)), the public key is different  either.

[image]

I don't know why there is no one certificate match with it, so I am not sure which certificate is signed by its CA. Hope someone can help me with it. Thank you!

Comment: The cert(s) field in an OCSP response contains the cert(s) used by the _OCSP responder_ (part of the CA) to sign the _response_, and must be different from the cert(s) used on the website or other 'application' server for SSL/TLS protocol. To see the data about the cert whose revocation is being checked, look in the tbsResponse for CertificateID. This is not a programming question or problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 How browser check the authenticity of a OCSP responder? Is its public key stored in the browser?

Comment: The responder's cert is validated like any other except that the revocation check may be suppressed or limited to avoid infinite regress -- see RFC6960 4.2.2.2.1. In most cases, including bing.com, the responder cert is issued by the same CA as the leaf cert, here `C=US, O=Microsoft Corporation, CN=Microsoft RSA TLS CA 01` which is turn is issued by `Baltimore CyberTrust Root` which is a well-known root in most truststores. What truststore a browser uses (for everything) depends on the browser, just as it always did before OCSP and stapling.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem.